# How to remove remote notifications on iOS 9 and below?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

How can I remove **remote** notifications on iOS 9 and below? On iOS 10 and above I can use this

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

But how about iOS 9 and below?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

Comment: @Malik not be badge.... The push notifications

Comment: Setting the badge to 0 clears out all push notifications

Comment: I am not increasing the badge when sending notification. Will it work anyways?

Comment: Pretty sure it will. Doesn't hurt to test anyway

Comment: no it's not working